# How to add 'show all' pages query to an existing URL?

Tags: javascript, json, canvas

Apologies for my lack of correct terminology but I am looking to view all results within one search page on our Canvas digital learning platform using a string/query appended to the URL.

For said search, there are currently 1300 pages, each with approximately 20 entries visible - I really want to be able to see all on one page given the need to see more than 20 entries at one time.

The end of the URL for default view of page is:
**/1?page=1**

The end of the URL for page 1300 is:
**/1?page=1300**

I have tried using a 'showall' function I found elsewhere but it does not seem to work.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks,
SB

Comment: Read more about your `existing URL` document.

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't a "just give me everything" parameter, but (if this is the correct Canvas I found the docs for) [there is a `per_page` parameter](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.pagination.html) you could try to increase:

> You can set a custom per-page amount with the `?per_page` parameter. There is an unspecified limit to how big you can set per_page to, so be sure to always check for the Link header.

Beyond increasing that, all you really can do is just iterate over however many pages there are, preferably using the "Next" `Link` header described in the docs above rather than increasing `page=`.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look into it shortly. Much appreciated and yes, that is the correct Canvas.